# Create pandas DataFrame from two lists with same keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two lists of tuples with the same keys as shown below. How can I create a pandas DataFrame with the key as the index and the values in columns?

```
l1 = [('jan', 1.2), ('feb', 1.3), ('mar', 1.1)]
l2 = [('jan', 1.1), ('feb', 1.2), ('mar', 1.3)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([dict(l1), dict(l2)]).transpose()
```

Comment: This creates a DataFrame with the column names as keys and values as rows.

Comment: @GauravBansal oh, just transpose it then. I added it to the answer